# Python скрипт и капча Yandex

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, requests-html

Такая ситуация, написал скрипт на pyhton для получения данных с yandex map/navi
Локально, в PyCharm отрабатывает на ура.
Залил скрипт на VDS. Не работат, Yandex отдаёт 403 попытка обойти капчу.
Поменял IP на VDS, не помогло, отдаёт 403 попытка обойти капчу.
User Agent отдаю. Если дёрнуть страницу curl`ом, капча не запрашивается.
В чём может быть причина?
код

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
st_accept = "text/html"
st_useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.517 Safari/537.36"
headers = {"Accept": st_accept, "User-Agent": st_useragent}

r = session.get(f'https://yandex.ru/navi', headers=headers)
r.html.render()
r_string = r.text
print(r_string)
```

Comment: Покажите для начала код, а так разве что погадать можно 

Comment: @Amgarak код добавил